# Variable prints somewhere but does not print somewhere else?

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++, and I've (accidentally) decided that Tic-Tac-Toe is a good place to start with my first mini project (not as easy as I thought...).

I've currently got this one problem that I can't fix, which is where a variable `(playerPlays)` is printing somewhere but not somewhere else.

```
void inputUpdatePlayerBoard() {
    if (playerInput[0] == 'A' && playerInput[1] == '1')  {
        //these two couts are to debug, but playerPlays prints nothing at all...
        cout << "bloopoop" << endl;
        cout << playerPlays << endl;
        if (playerPlays == 'A') {
        cout << "playerInputSucceeded" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal with this part of my code is to check if the `(playerInput)` is a certain cell and the current player, then update the board to reflect the changes.
However, in the `(if nested in the if)`, I can't seem to get the expected value for `(playerPlays)` when I get the expected value somewhere else.

I must say that printing is not what I want, but just a way to check what is stored inside there, which apparently is nothing.

I am not referencing any tic-tac-toes done by others as I want to explore and learn myself.
Attached below is my full code.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "brains.hpp"
using namespace std;

bool firstPlay = true;
char playerInput[2];
unsigned int microsecond = 1000000;
char playerNow = 'A';
char playerPlays;
char A1 = ' ', A2 = ' ', A3 = ' ', B1 = ' ', B2 = ' ', B3 = ' ', C1 = ' ', C2 = ' ', C3 = ' ';
char playBoard[] = {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3};

void currentPlayer() {
    if (playerNow == 'A') {
        playerPlays = 'A';
        playerNow = 'B';
    }
    else if (playerNow == 'B') {
        playerPlays = 'B';
        playerNow = 'A';
    }
    else {
        cout << "bloop currentPlayer failed" << endl;
    }
}

void clearScreen()
  {
  int n;
  for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    printf( "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" );
  }

void gameEnd() {
    clearScreen();
    cout << "Game has ended. Player has won!" << endl;
}

void inputUpdatePlayerBoard() {
    if (playerInput[0] == 'A' && playerInput[1] == '1')  {
        cout << "bloopoop" << endl;
        cout << playerPlays << endl;
        if (playerPlays == 'A') {
        cout << "playerInputSucceeded" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void winLogic() {
    if (A1 == A2 == A3)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
    else if (B1 == B2 == B3)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
    else if (C1 == C2 == C3)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
    else if (A1 == B1 == C1)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
    else if (A2 == B2 == C2)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
    else if (A3 == B3 == C3)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
    else if (A1 == B2 == C3)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
    else if (A3 == B2 == C1)
    {
        gameEnd();
    }
}



void roundStart () {
    clearScreen();
    cout << "===================" << endl;
    cout << "   Tic-Tac-Choop" << endl;
    cout << "===================" << endl;
    cout << "|     |     |     |" << endl;
    cout << "|  " << playBoard[0] <<"  |  " << playBoard[1] << "  |  " << playBoard[2] << "  |" << endl;
    cout << "|     |     |     |" << endl;
    cout << "|-----|-----|-----|" << endl;
    cout << "|     |     |     |" << endl;
    cout << "|  " << playBoard[3] <<"  |  " << playBoard[4] << "  |  " << playBoard[5] << "  |" << endl;
    cout << "|     |     |     |" << endl;
    cout << "|-----|-----|-----|" << endl;
    cout << "|     |     |     |" << endl;
    cout << "|  " << playBoard[6] <<"  |  " << playBoard[7] << "  |  " << playBoard[8] << "  |" << endl;
    cout << "|     |     |     |" << endl;
    cout << "===================" << endl << endl;
    currentPlayer();
    cout << playerPlays << playerNow << endl;
    cout << "Player " << playerPlays << "! Please make your move:" << endl;
    scanf("%s", playerInput);
    inputUpdatePlayerBoard();
    winLogic();
    cout << playerInput << endl;
    cout << playerInput[0] <<endl;
    cout << playerInput[1] <<endl;
}

int main() {
    if (firstPlay == true) {
        cout << "Welcome!" << endl;
        usleep(0.5 * microsecond);
        cout << "This is Mark's Tic-Tac-Choop!" <<endl;
        usleep(0.5 * microsecond);
        cout << "Version: 1.0 alpha." << endl;
        usleep(0.5 * microsecond);
        cout << "To begin, press ENTER." << endl;
        getchar();
        cout << "ENTER has been successfully pressed!" << endl;
        usleep(0.5 * microsecond);
        cout << "Round starting in 3..." << usleep(1 * microsecond) << "2..." << usleep(1 * microsecond) << "1..." << endl;
        firstPlay = false;
        roundStart();
    }
    else {
        cout << "bloop" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a metric ton of code here. Can you reduce it? Do we need all of these unrelated print statements? Do we need all of these unrelated usleep statements?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I should have removed everything unnecessary, I'll do that in future @BillLynch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a buffer overflow when you do `scanf("%s", playerInput);`. It looks like you pass that a string like "A1", which is three characters long (2 characters plus the terminating null character)

Otherwise, this appears to be working: https://godbolt.org/z/rcddqzr35

```
Welcome!
This is Mark's Tic-Tac-Choop!
Version: 1.0 alpha.
To begin, press ENTER.
ENTER has been successfully pressed!

===================
   Tic-Tac-Choop
===================
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|-----|-----|-----|
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|-----|-----|-----|
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
===================

playerPlays: A
playerNow: B
Player A! Please make your move:
bloopoop
playerPlays: A
playerInputSucceeded
A1
A
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's one new thing learned today, never thought that the issue could lie in the scanf.